# Why did Harry touch his cheeks when he turned into Goyle?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-chamber-of-secrets

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, once Harry had turned into Goyle after taking Polyjuice Potion, why did he touch his cheeks and forehead?

Comment: .... to feel what its like to have a different face?  to make sure that what he was seeing in the mirror was "real".

Answer (score 3):

Because he is in the second year at Hogwarts, and that was the first ever time he had taken polyjuice potion, he was seeing whether his eyes were lying to him about the transformation.
As some potions can make you hallucinate, its sometimes best to use your sense of touch as well, because you don't know if your eyes are lying to you.

He probably also was horrified for transforming into one of the most ugliest, meanest and most hideous second year in the school...also probs couldn't believe he was getting a feeling of turning into a Slytherin.